# Is there any ssh scan record program?

Tags: ssh, network-scanner

I have a CentOS Server, and I found so many SSH Scanner scanning my Server, I want to record all the Scanner source IPs, and set them into my firewall.

So, who can help to recommend any SSH Scanner record software?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `fail2ban` - although it doesn't care about SSH specifically, it will do exactly what you are asking for (and then some).

What it does do is let you specify what logs to watch, and keywords to watch for - like "authentication failed".  After X number of those in Y seconds, it will automatically add a firewall rule for you.